Expected volume of a tetrahedron formed by four random points within the unit sphere
Motivated by the question: Expected area of triangle formed by three random points inside unit circle, I have been wondering whether this result can be solved for 3 dimensions.
Suppose that four points are picked randomly (uniformly) within a unit sphere. What is the expected value of the volume of the tetrahedron formed by connecting these four points?
I have been having trouble applying the same method that was used to solve the 2-dimensional case but it looks like this method can be used to solve the problem for higher dimensions, making me think that the following generalized question can be answered:
Suppose that $n+1$ points are picked randomly (uniformly) within a unit $n$-dimensional hypersphere. What is the expected value of the volume of the $n$-dimensional tetrahedron formed by connecting these $n+1$ points?

I believe that the mean squared distance between 2 points in a unit n-dimensional ball is $2n/(n+2)$. But I've only proved it for small n, and it's slow to test by brute force for large n (because you have to reject a lot of random points).

I found a better random ball point algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544972/4014959 In my tests on the 3D ball, the volume is a little over 0.0527, roughly $1/(\pi 3!)$

See OEIS https://oeis.org/A093591 .

Thanks, @Hugo! That page has a link to The expected volume of a random polytope in a ball, by  Fernando Affentranger (1988), but unfortunately it's paywalled.

If you are interested in the non-trivial details of the 3D case, I'd recommend the Solomon reference given in A093951. Pages 117-124 "Sylvester's problem in three dimensions".

Yes, the expected volume can be given in closed form, with the help of a generalization of Sylvester's Four-Point Problem.
The general term for members of the series (point, line, triangle, tetrahedron, ...) is simplex. The volume of an n-simplex can be easily calculated  from a determinant constructed from the coordinates of its vertices, divided by n factorial.
We can calculate the expected volume of a random n-simplex in a unit hypersphere via equation (3) from the linked MathWorld page. We also need the equation for the volume of the unit n-dimensional hypersphere:
$$V(n) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}$$
where $\Gamma()$ is the gamma function. For all $z$, $$\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$$
For non-negative integer $n$,
$$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$$
and
$$\Gamma(n+\frac12) = \left(\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!}
\right)\sqrt{\pi}$$
Note that $V(0)=1$.
The Sylvester equation uses the binomial coefficient, in particular, the generalized central binomial coefficient, which can be written in terms of the gamma function:
$$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)^2}$$
The equation for the expected simplex volume is:
$$S(n) = \frac{\dbinom{(n+1)}{(n+1)/2}^{n+1}}{2^n\dbinom{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2/2}} \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}
$$
Here are the results for small $n$, computed using SageMath:
Exact expected volume



n
Expected volume




0
$1$


1
$\frac{2}{3}$


2
$\frac{35}{48 \, \pi}$


3
$\frac{12}{715} \, \pi$


4
$\frac{676039}{7776000 \, \pi^{2}}$


5
$\frac{32000}{272254059} \, \pi^{2}$


6
$\frac{107492012277}{27536588800000 \, \pi^{3}}$


7
$\frac{21008750000}{56100739008446649} \, \pi^{3}$


8
$\frac{109701233401363445369}{1210054852352102400000000 \, \pi^{4}}$


9
$\frac{527046113468915712}{778482596802192849805651985} \, \pi^{4}$



To 6 significant figures



n
Expected volume




0
1.00000


1
0.666667


2
0.232101


3
0.0527260


4
0.00880878


5
0.00116005


6
0.000125897


7
0.0000116113


8
9.30694e-7


9
6.59476e-8



Here's the Sage / Python script to do those calculations.
As $n\to\infty$,
$-\log(S(n))$ converges approximately to $$1.322365 - 0.5n + n\log(n)$$
It converges quite quickly. In this plot, the green curve is that function and the blue dots are $-\log(S(n))$.

Here's the plotting script.
Here's a Sage / Python script that computes the expected volume by random sampling using the technique given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54544972/4014959 to generate the uniformly distributed points. The script generates ~500,000 points and then finds the mean of 100 partitions of simplexes formed from those points.
